# Forecast of electricity consumption of tens of thousands of households (largeVis cluster results)

Tags: clustering, predictive-models, prediction

I have the tens of thousands of household electricity consumption time series data, from January 2012 to December 2015 monthly data.

Because most household electricity consumption behavior very different (I have plot the time series). So I think maybe should do the cluster analysis, then model for every cluster.

This is what i got using the largeVis method:
[image]

What's meaning of this cluster results? Should i cluster the household? or is there necessary model for every cluster?

```
elect_data <- read.csv("test_gm_data.csv") 
library(largeVis)
set.seed(123)
ts_matrix_elec <- elect_data %>% scale() %>% t()
visObject <- largeVis(ts_matrix_elec, n_trees = 50,
                  K = 20)
plot(t(visObject$coords))
```

Comment: I do not see any clusters there, do you?

Comment: It seems no clusters, how to interpreting this plot? or is there any method for this problem?